# I want to make sure theres not two duplicates when making an API call

Tags: javascript, arrays

Im not sure how to filter a word so that it doesn't come back in two segments. I don't want duplicate names basically.

`

```
fetch(typeURL2)
            .then(function (response2) {
              return response2.json();
            })
            .then(function (data2) {
             const type2takes2x = data2.damage_relations.double_damage_from;
              const doubleNames = [];
              for (var j = 0; j < takes2xBucket.length; j++) {
                doubleNames.push(takes2xBucket[j].name);
              }
for (var i = 0; i < type2takes2x.length; i++) {
                if ((doubleNames.includes(type2takes2x[i].name))) {
                  times4xBucket.push(type2takes2x[i]);
                }
                 else if((times4xBucket.filter(doubleNames[i].name))) {
                  takes2xBucket.push(type2takes2x[i]);

                } 
                
              }
```

`

this is the code, but im not sure if "filter" is the correct way to remove the duplicates off.

Comment: Can you include some examples of inputs and desired outputs? It's not very clear what you're trying to achieve. And what does this have to do with API calls?

Comment: sorry about that, basically its a call that uses pokemon to see what they are weak against....Example: a water/flying pokemon is 4x times weaker to thunder but the problem is that theres 5 categories. No Effect, 1/4 effect, 1/2 effect, 2x effect, and 4x effect. But thunder would be called twice and it would appear in both 2x and 4x. i only want it to appear in 4x. so i need a way to filter out the duplicate. @LawrenceWebDev

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to answer the question without data. I think you're working with an object and not an array but still, this might help you. You can try converting the array into a set.

```
let myArr = ['thunder', 'thunder', 'water', 'earth'];
const mySet = new Set([...myArr]); //Convert to set. Set doesn't allow duplicates
console.log(mySet); // We're expecting a set: Set(3) {'thunder', 'water', 'earth'}
myArr = [...mySet]; // Convert back to array.
console.log(myArr); // We're expecting an array: (3) ['thunder', 'water', 'earth']
```